# Designing a grabber

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, mechanisms, solidworks, mechanical

I designed a grabber for grabbing strings and yarns. the movement that I need is straight up and down to grab a piece of yarn. I wanted to know if this model (in the video) works in real life or not.

1- How would I find out that if this model is legit and practical in the machine that I'm designing. (I am a beginner and this is my first project ever!) ?

2- How can I build these parts that I designed in real life? (is there any workshop or ... for it?)

3- Also if you have seen any other ideas or design that is less complex than this grabber please let me know.
[image]
[image]

Video link of this design : youtube.com/watch?v=GbeDwZN51vg

Comment: Could you provide more details on your design? It is not clear to me how this is intended to work.

Comment: This video will do it : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbeDwZN51vg

Comment: You need to show the mechanism that moves the light blue link, and the function and flexibility of the green pieces on the back. So far, I don't see it can work.

Comment: green pieces are fixed. I wanted to design the mechanism to move that light blue link later. I just wanted to make sure that if I move that light blue link it will work as a grabber

Comment: But the mechanism behind moving the light blue link probably will be (circular to linear) movement that if you google you can find it. Again if there is a better idea please let me know

Comment: put https:// in front of the URL to make it clickable

Comment: Here is the clickable link : https://youtube.com/watch?v=GbeDwZN51vg

Comment: I think asking "how to build these parts" is too broad for a real answer on this website. I don't think this mechanism is the best one. But I think it is great that you want to build one, so here are some directions: I think what you need is to **buy some materials and tools and experiment! There is no substitute for real experience.** LEGO Technic is great for this, but I am **guessing** that unfortunately you are in a relatively poor country and such things are very expensive there. You can also try making mechanisms from scrap wood, plastic you can buy, or even cardboard.

Comment: You can of course pay a workshop to build the parts you want, but it will be more expensive than playing around at home. That's why I recommend just playing with mechanisms in general, to learn how things work in the real world. For example, I think that in the real world, the weight of the right side of the mechanism (if it is heavy) will create a force on the green pins that will makes it hard for the mechanism to slide on the green pins.

Comment: But then again, it might work well. I don't know. Only the real world ultimately matters and if the prediction doesn't match the real world then the prediction is useless.

Comment: It may also help if you explain the purpose of the grabber. Is it a part of a bigger machine? If it's part of a bigger machine, how does the light blue bar move? How will this mechanism be mounted in the machine - which direction is up and down? (that is important because of gravity) Or is it designed for someone to hold it in their hand and move the light blue bar with their hand?

Comment: If this is not the best model that you know, can you please tell me what better mechanism for grabbers you have in mind?

Comment: This is a small part of a machine that I'm trying to build. The purpose for that grabber is to catch a string (yarn) tip

Comment: But this is my first experience to design a mechanical mechanism. I've been trying to design and build this machine for 6 months now. this is the only place I can ask experts a question, because in real life I couldn't find anyone.

Comment: What part of the machine will cause the blue bar to move?

Comment: And how do the yarns fit into this mechanism? Do they get stuck between the two main bars when they move together? Is that how it works? I am wondering why the right side has this ---C shape.

Comment: Yarn is going through the C shape area. The shape is like "C" because I want another grabber to grab the yarn from this grabber (handing the yarn over from one grabber to another). So the second grabber will grab the yarn from the empty area of the first grabber tips and when the second grabber took the yarn then the first grabber will let it go. It is C shape so I can hand it over to another grabber